# Opensea isApprovedForAll / ProxyRegistry for Ethereum (Rinkeby) and Polygon (Mumbai)

Tags: polygon, opensea

Can somebody explain why there are different implementations suggested by OpenSea for the isApprovedForAll for Ethereum (Rinkeby) and Polygon (Mumbai).
The Ethereum (Rinkeby) version from ERC721Tradable.sol

```
/**
 * Used to delegate ownership of a contract to another address, to save on unneeded transactions to approve contract use for users
 */
contract ProxyRegistry {
    mapping(address => OwnableDelegateProxy) public proxies;
}

/**
 * @title ERC721Tradable
 * ERC721Tradable - ERC721 contract that whitelists a trading address, and has minting functionality.
 */

abstract contract ERC721Tradable is  ....

    /**
     * Override isApprovedForAll to whitelist user's OpenSea proxy accounts to enable gas-less listings.
     */
    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, IERC721)
        returns (bool)
    {
        // Whitelist OpenSea proxy contract for easy trading.
        ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
        if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)) == operator) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.isApprovedForAll(owner, operator);
    }
```

For Polygon (Mumbai) Opensea tells me to override this function by

```
   /**
   * Override isApprovedForAll to auto-approve OS's proxy contract
   */
    function isApprovedForAll(
        address _owner,
        address _operator
    ) public override view returns (bool isOperator) {
      // if OpenSea's ERC721 Proxy Address is detected, auto-return true
        if (_operator == address(0x58807baD0B376efc12F5AD86aAc70E78ed67deaE)) {
            return true;
        }
        
        // otherwise, use the default ERC721.isApprovedForAll()
        return ERC721.isApprovedForAll(_owner, _operator);
    }
```

Why is the first implementation (Ethereum) designed so complex with using a helper object (like discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70492216/solidity-default-constructor-with-address-parameter/70494102) whereas the implementation for Polygon just compares against the proxy address? Both implementations are the OpenSea recommendations.